# How to Make a Global Object Thread-Safe

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library, async-await

All, I have a concurrency problem with a large application I have recently multi-threaded. The problem is within a script processor that can run batch jobs

```
public async Task<Result> ProcessScriptAsync(
    CancellationTokenSource cancelSource,
    TaskScheduler uiScheduler)
{
    ...
    // Get instance of active workbook on UI thread.
    IWorkbook workbook = this.workbookView.ActiveWorkbook;
    while (notFinished)
    {
        ...
        Task<bool> runScriptAsyncTask = null;
        runScriptAsyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
        {
            return RunScript(ref workbook);
        }, this.token,
           TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
           TaskScheduler.Default);
        // Some cancellation support here...

        // Run core asynchroniously.
        try
        {
            bGenerationSuccess = await runScriptAsyncTask;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Handle cancellation.
        }
        finally 
        {
            // Clean up.
        }
    }
...
}
```

My problem comes when you consider the `RunScript` method. The object being passed in to `RunScript` is not thread safe and was created on the UI thread. As such, I have to create a 'deep copy' of this object inside the `RunScript` method...

```
private bool RunScript(ref IWorkbook workbook)
{
    ...
    // Get a new 'shadow' workbook with which to operate on from a background thread.
    IWorkbook shadowWorkbook;
    if (File.Exists(workbook.FullName)) 
    {
        // This opens a workbook from disk. The Factory.GetWorkbook method is thread safe.
        shadowWorkbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(workbook.FullName); // (##)
    }
    else
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
            "The current workbook is not saved to disk. This is a requirement. " + 
            "To facilitate multi-threading!");

    // Do hard work here...
    shadowWorkbook.WorkbookSet.GetLock();
    try
    {
        // Do work and add worksheets to shadowWorkbook.
    }
    finally
    {
        // Reassign the UI workbook object to our new shadowWorkbook which 
        // has been worked on. This is fine to do as not work is actually being 
        // done on workbook.
        workbook = shadowWorkbook;
        shadowWorkbook.WorkbookSet.ReleaseLock();
    }
}
```

My problem is on line marked by (##). Each time `RunScript` is executed is creates a new `shadowWorkbook` from disk. The problem with this is that some worksheets are created in the `shadowWorkbook` which are subsequently copied back to `workbook` at the end of the processing. However, each time I execute `RunScript` I get the workbook from disk which does not have the new sheets generated in the last loop.

I have looked into making `shadowWorkbook` a global object but it is created on the UI thread and thus cannot subsequently be used from my background operation. One way around this is to save the workbook to disk after each worksheet creation, but there are a lot of creations and this would be expensive.

**Is there a way to make `shadowWorkbook` global *and* thread-safe, enabling me to persist changes to my `IWorkbook` across thread invocations?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe [Volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) is what you are looking for

Comment: @noobob maybe not. What would `volatile` do in this specific situation ? And to which field should it be applied?

Comment: Are you saying you want to modify the file from several threads at the same time? I'm afraid there is no simple way to do that.

Comment: No, I recognise that this is not possible. The issue I am having is to do with having to create a new instance of the `workbook` object each time my background thread needs to do work. In a batch procedure, the `RunScript` method is called many times, and each time work is done of `shadowWorkbook` - the problems is I cannot persist changes to `shadowWorkbook` between calls to run script without performing a 'hard' save (i.e. writing to disk) which is expensive. I want to know how I can make `shadowWorkbook` global, without causing cross thread problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I would say that the mutable resource at `this.workbookView.ActiveWorkbook` needs to be thread safe in this situation. Your workbook object you say is created on the UI thread, hence you will get contention for it there and in the task threads when you assign `workbook = shadowWorkbook`.

Perhaps declare a synchronisation object, e.g.:

```
private static Object _objectLock = new Object();
```

and use like so in your RunScript method (and anywhere else your workbook is modified) to ensure serial access to the resource from different threads:

```
lock(_objectLock)
{
    workbook.AddWorkSheet();
}
```

In this case you won't need to deep copy your workbook, hence remove that expensive call and all the extra complexity it creates.

Comment: +1 thanks for the idea, but this is not going to work for me. When you say "the mutable resource at this.workbookView.ActiveWorkbook needs to be thread safe in this situation" that _would_ be great but it is not and this is third party library. Assignment of the `workbook` (UI thread owned) object is not the problem, persistence of the `shadowWorkbook` for repetitive use from the background thread (without thread context switching) is what is desired.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you should do is for each `workbook` create a `Thread`. On that `Thread`, create your `shadowWorkbook`, and then run a loop that processes requests for that workbook, using something like `BlockingCollection<Action<IWorkbook>>`.

You would use that by writing something like

```
workbookManager.Run(workbook, w => /* do work and add worksheets to w */);
```

Comment: Cheers for the idea. The operations that are perform on the `IWorkbook` objects must be sequential; it's not clear that this approach would help my problem either, on each thread I would still have the problem that I would need to create an `IWorkbook` object when each thread was started and to do that in a thread safe way would require the use of `shadowWorkbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(workbook.FullName);` which is opening up an instance on the relevant thread - a want to persist the use of `shadowWorkbook` between executions. I have currently added saves to get around this...

Comment: +1 for your help. Thanks very much. Thinking about this it does not seem like this is going to be possible using my current design...